# Tic Tac Toe (Player vs Computer)

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, tic-tac-toe

I am looking on how I can improve my writing style and/or how to simplify how I write my code.

```
# USER: TCG
# Tic Tac Toe (User vs Computer)

import random

def place(num,x):
    # Returns all the moves made
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i] == num:
            pos = x.index(num)
            return x[(pos + 1)]
    return str(num)

def print_grid(move,player,x):

    pos_list.extend([move,player])

    # Grid on which the player and computer play on            
    grid = ["","-------------\n",
        "|",place(1,pos_list),"|",place(2,pos_list),"|",place(3,pos_list),"|\n",
        "|---+---+---|\n",
        "|",place(4,pos_list),"|",place(5,pos_list),"|",place(6,pos_list),"|\n",
        "|---+---+---|\n",
        "|",place(7,pos_list),"|",place(8,pos_list),"|",place(9,pos_list),"|\n",
        "-------------\n"]
    if x == 2:
        # Only prints one the player has made a move
        print '\n', ' '.join(grid)

def winner(x,player,xx):

    # Checks if there is a winner (Really messy, could do with code simplifying)
    if ((1 in x and 4 in x and 7 in x)or(1 in x and 2 in x and 3 in x)or(2 in x and 5 in x and 8 in x)or(3 in x and 6 in x and 9 in x)or
    (4 in x and 5 in x and 6 in x)or(7 in x and 8 in x and 9 in x)or(1 in x and 5 in x and 9 in x)or(3 in x and 5 in x and 7 in x)):
    # If prevents the A.I part from printing the statemnt
        if xx <> 1:
            print '\n'*5,"\'%s\'" %player, "HAS WON!"
        return 1 == 1

def computer_AI_part(listx):
    global computer_move

    # Chceks all possible values which the player can and enter to win and blocks it
    for x in range(1,10):
        if x not in pos_list:
            listx.append(x)
            if (winner(listx,'Computer',1)) == True:
                del listx[-1]
                computer_move = x
                return 1
            del listx[-1]

def computer_and_player():
    global computer_move,pos_list,player_list,computer_list
    replay,draw = 0,0

    while True:

        # Replay's the game
        if replay == 1:
            restart = raw_input("Would you like to replay?: ")
            if restart == "yes":
                pass
            else:
                return
        else:
            print "\nTic Tac Toe - Computer vs You", '\n'*2,"Computer goes first\n"

        replay,computer_move,players_move,loop_count,pos_list,player_list,computer_list = 0,0,0,0,[],[],[]

        for each in "XXXXX":
            loop_count += 1

            # Computer's Move
            if computer_AI_part(computer_list) or computer_AI_part(player_list) == 1:
                pass     
            else:
                while True:
                    computer_move = random.randint(1,9)
                    if computer_move in pos_list:
                        continue
                    break
            computer_list.append(computer_move)
            # Prints Grid
            print_grid(computer_move,'O',2)

            if loop_count == 5:
                if winner(player_list,'player',2) == True or winner(computer_list,'Computer',2) == True:
                    pass
                else:
                    print "Match Was a draw!"
                replay = 1
                break

            # Checks winner
            if winner(computer_list,'Computer',2) == True:
                replay = 1
                break

            # Player's Move
            while True:
                try:
                    players_move = int(raw_input("\n\'%s\' Enter a value from the grid to plot your move: " %each))
                    if players_move in pos_list or players_move < 1 or players_move > 9:
                        print "Enter an available number that's between 1-9"
                        continue
                    break
                except:
                    print "Enter a number"

            player_list.append(players_move)
            # Sets player's move for printing
            print_grid(players_move,each,1)

            # Checks winner again
            if winner(player_list,'player',1) == True:
                print_grid(players_move,each,2)
                winner(player_list,'player',2)
                replay = 1
                break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    computer_and_player()
```

Update: [new version](https://gist.github.com/overlordofdoom1/78b36febd124afc169f0720b75710e72)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a section of my game:

> ```
> 'X' Enter a value from the grid to plot your move: exit
> Enter a number
>
> 'X' Enter a value from the grid to plot your move: leave
> Enter a number
>
> 'X' Enter a value from the grid to plot your move: quit
> Enter a number
>
> 'X' Enter a value from the grid to plot your move: ^CEnter a number
> ```

I was just trying to do a short test, and then go back to the code and make some more changes, but I couldn't get out of the program without finishing the game.  It's good that you don't allow just anything, but `^C` at least should let me get out.

---

Your `place()` function could be a little better by using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
def place(num,x):
    # Returns the value in x at position num
    for i, v in enumerate(x):
        if v == num:
            return x[(i + 1)]
    return str(num)
```

Your naming could still be improved.  How is one to know that `x` is a list of positions and values?  There's more that I would change, but I'll get to that below.

---

You have a function called `print_grid` that makes a move, too.  Either create a new function to make the move or rename the current function to show that it has side effects.

---

Global variables are almost never necessary.  If you are tempted, you might be better off either passing them as arguments or defining a class.  In this case, I think a class would be the better option.

---

`pos_list` would be better off being a dictionary (of course with a different name).  It would be `{pos: value, pos: value, ...}` instead of `[pos, value, pos, value, ...]`.  That way, lookups are easier.  For example, `place()` could be `return x.get(num, str(num))` -- just one line!

---

Your grid is a little hard to follow.  It would be better to have a template and fill it in:

```
    template = """
-------------
| {} | {} | {} |
|-----------|
| {} | {} | {} |
|-----------|
| {} | {} | {} |
--------------"""


    if x == 2:
        # Only prints if the player has made a move
        print template.format(*(place(num + 1, pos_list) for num in range(9)))
```

---

To be frank, I agree with you comment in `winner()` that the code is messy.  I would define tuples of valid moves and see if any of them is a match:

```
def winner(x,player,xx):
    wins = ((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), # Horizontal
            (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9), # Vertical
            (1, 5, 9), (3, 5, 7)) # Diagonal

    if any(all(pos in x for pos in win) for win in wins):
        if xx != 1:
            print '\n'*5, "'{}'".format(player), "HAS WON!"
        return True
    return False
```

I changed `if xx <> 1:` to `if xx != 1:` because it's a little more obvious what it means.  In fact, Python 3 took out `<>` so you need to use `!=`.  I also changed your `print` statement.  You didn't need to escape `'` because it was `"` that made it a string, so the `'` wouldn't close the string.  Also, while `%` is not officially deprecated, it is recommended to use [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).  While I was at it, I changed `return 1 == 1` to `return True`.  Why make Python evaluate an expression when you already know the answer?

---

> ```
> def computer_AI_part(listx):
> ```

Every function does its part.  You never need the word `part` in its name.  Also, `listx` isn't very descriptive.  What sort of list is it?  Is it a list of `moves`?

> ```
> while True:
>
>     # Replay's the game
>     if replay == 1:
>         restart = raw_input("Would you like to replay?: ")
>         if restart == "yes":
>             pass
>         else:
>             return
>     else:
>         print "\nTic Tac Toe - Computer vs You", '\n'*2,"Computer goes first\n"
> ```

Since `replay` is always either `0` or `1`, and since `0` is `False` and `1` is `True`, you can simply say `if replay:`.  I would also change the logic slightly.  If I typed `y` or `Yes`, your program would just exit.  I would do something more like:

```
while True:

    # Replay's the game
    if replay:
        restart = raw_input("Would you like to replay?: ").lower()
        if restart in ("y", "yes"): 
            pass
        elif restart in ("n", "no"):
            return
        else:
            print "Say 'yes' or 'no'"
            continue
    else:
        print "\nTic Tac Toe - Computer vs You", '\n'*2,"Computer goes first\n"
```

It's only barely longer, and it is much more user-friendly.

---

> ```
> replay,computer_move,players_move,loop_count,pos_list,player_list,computer_list = 0,0,0,0,[],[],[]
> ```

That's hard to read.  If you want to put them all together like that, you should at least add some whitespace and put the different types on different lines:

```
replay, computer_move, players_move, loop_count = 0, 0, 0, 0
pos_list, player_list, computer_list = [], [], []
```

That's a lot easier to read.

---

> ```
> if computer_move in pos_list:
>     continue
> break
> ```

Why not:

```
if computer_move not in pos_list:
    break
```

That's a little easier to understand.

---

```
 if winner(computer_list,'Computer',2) == True:
```

`winner()` already returns a boolean.  Checking its equality with `True` is redundant because it will result ... in the same boolean.

---

> ```
> except:
>     print "Enter a number"
> ```

You have certain expectations for what errors could happen.  I would change this to:

```
except ValueError:
    print "Enter a number"
except (EOFError, KeyboardInterrupt):
    exit()
```

Yay!  That fixed my original problem of not being able to exit.

---

> ```
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     computer_and_player()
> ```

Excellent!  I can import your functions without running the whole code.

Comment: Also when I pass computer_move as an argument and say `move = x` within that function, computer_move is never assigned to x.

Comment: @TCG: That's why I suggested a class.  Often, you can pass a variable to a function and then reassign it to what the function returns.  In this case, `computer_move` is used by too many things, so I would define a class and use `self.computer_move` instead of a global variable.